# Python argparse: diiference between -o and --option

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to understand the `argparse` package and I really can't find an answer to this very simple question:

- What is the difference between `-a` and `--argument` when adding an argument?

Sometimes, I find both in one `add_argument()` like here:

```py
parser.add_argument(
        "-f", "--file",
        help="file path"
        )
```

Comment: It's entirely up to the implementor. Do you want peeps to be able to pass `--option` or not. There is no difference between them in practice. `argparse` has the machinery to handle either input.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492544/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-commands

Comment: `argparse` is following POSIX (linux) conventions for short and long option flags.  While there are some detailed differences in how they are handled, they are basically synonyms.  And you can use more than these two.

Answer (score 3):

If both are specified, then argparse will store the value in the long form ('argument') rather than the short form ('a'). It will infer the destination, so "--foo-bar" will be stored in `foo_bar`.

You can mash together short forms and use a single hyphen (`-af`) but unlike some *NIX commands, order is important: If your argument requires a value (`-f filename`) then the argument *must* appear as the final argument of the group of short-form arguments:

```
cmd -af my_file   # works
cmd -fa my_file   # does not work
```

Compare this with the monster `tar(1)` which allows `tar -cfC myfile.tar ./directory` and will correctly sort it out as logically equivalent to `tar -c -f myfile.tar -C ./directory`. Also, some long forms allow the use of '=' when specifying the option `tar -cf myfile.tar`, versus `tar -c --file=myfile.tar`. You cannot use '=' on short forms.

Fortunately, python argparse doesn't care about '='. Use it or not, with short form or long form.

```
# All equivalent:
  cmd -af=my_file
  cmd -a -f my_file
  cmd -a -fmy_file
  cmd -afmy_file
  cmd --file my_file -a
  cmd --file=my_file -a
```

Does it matter? As another answer suggests, the long form can help with readability. Short form can make your power-users happier.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to capture the spirit of the '-' vs '--'.

Just to be succinct, both the type of parameters are equally capable. I can't think of anything that you can do in one type but not in another (except mashing single chars with single hyphen which usually python programmers don't do.).

- `-`

  - Known as short-form parameter.
  - E.g. `-f filename`
  - Use this for parameters that will be either always used or easily understood by the user of your program.
  - Usually this is always present.
- `--`

  - Known as long-form parameter name.
  - E.g. `--directory /root/foobar`
  - This format is usually used only when you have multiple competing single characters for the parameter. E.g. if your code accepts `d`irectory and `d`ate, then better mention the long form options for both.
  - This type is not always present (unless you have a mild OCD about providing short and long form always.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be easier to use long option names, especially with vague names or when the short options are hard to come by, and sometimes it's just the opposite. If you think that might be the situation, you can put in both forms of options, and let the user choose his favorite.

Would you prefer `script.py -r1000` or `script.py --repeat 1000`? I'd say it's all about taste, and if you're dealing with a lot of people using it, you might want to consider theirs.

> What is the difference between `-a` and `--argument` when adding an argument?

As long as you add them both in the `add_argument` function, the answer is - with `-a` you can stick the values (if there are any) right after the `-a`, no space required, like the example in the second paragraph. That's aside, none.