# AttributeError: 'Argument' object has no attribute 'dest'

Tags: python, selenium, arguments, command, pytest

Can anyone tell me, why I got the attribute error for this code

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    Parser.addoption(“—browser”)

def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption(“—browser”)
```

Comment: _AttributeError_ at which line? Update the question with the error stacktrace.

Comment: Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly, It will help readers to understand your problem and you will get relevant answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code snippet you provided, I assume you're trying to add commandline options to [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html).

As the error says, the Argument object created by `Parser.addoption` needs a `dest` attribute.

Try using double hyphens, i.e. [long options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555973/python-argparse-diiference-between-o-and-option#44556265):

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    Parser.addoption(“-—browser”)

def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption(“-—browser”)
```

these get stored as `dest` attributes by default by pytest when `dest` is not provided.